# how to add/replace a syscall to hp-ux (hp unix) 11iv3?

Tags: unix, system-calls, hp-ux

I need to replace/add a syscall on hp unix 11iv3, but I can't find a way to do this .who can help me ? if anyone can  tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "replace" it for a specific program (like one asking for sysid) you may use the LD_PRELOAD environment variable to load your own library which would implement a similar function as the one you want to "replace".

Comment: thank you, I know that, but I MUST replace some syscall routine， because our product is based on this　technology. Have a ook at [link](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/System-Administration/dlkm-compiled-error/m-p/5184178). When I use the function(sysent_assign()) of scall_kernprivate.h, the kernel oops, I guess we maybe use those fuctions incorrectly , how to use them ?! Help me !!!